# Detecting Peaks

Tags: r, graph

I have a big dataset. In a graph of an EMG. I need to find the peaks in the graph. on the Y graph is the EMG value on the x side is datapoints. How do I detect the peaks in the graph. I need 10 peaks. I used this one but I am not sure what to fill in everywhere

```
findpeaks(x, nups = 1, ndowns = nups, zero = "0", peakpat = NULL, minpeakheight = -Inf, minpeakdistance = 1, threshold = 0, npeaks = 0, sortstr = FALSE)
```

but I don't get what is nups it gives an error nups is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/findpeaks

Read the documentation for this function.

Note that these function parameters are already filled out with a value `nups = 1, ndowns = nups`

There's an example at the bottom of the page `findpeaks(pSignal, npeaks=3, threshold=4, sortstr=TRUE)`

Your peak finding function only requires the data and possibly number of peaks to return and threshold.

Comment: For clarification: nups = minimum number of increasing steps before a peak is reached which implies that a peak would not be reached if your graph looked like 1,1,1,9,1,1,1 and you required nups = 2 for example.

Comment: When I try the function of findpeaks it returns the whole time nups is not there. What should I do as following?